# Plotting Legends in GGPLOT with Mutiple Time Series

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R, I am trying to work on multiple time series plots with ggplot but however as much as I have tired, there seems to be an issue with plotting legends.
I have tried to use +theme(legends.) but this also is not giving any outputs.
Given below is the code, would it be possible for anyone to have a look into this and let me know how to plot the legends in this situation.
The datasets here contains gross revenue of these companies over the span of 2009-2020.

```
ggplot(dataset,aes(x=Year,y=Apple))+geom_line(color=5)+geom_line(aes(x=Year,y=Intel),colour=10)+geom_line(aes(x=Year,y=BOB),color=11)+geom_line(aes(x=Year,y=Airbus),color=12)+geom_line(aes(x=Year,y=SYNTEL),color=13)+geom_line(aes(x=Year,y=Google),color=14)+geom_line(aes(x=Year,y=Ebay),color=15)+ theme_light() +labs(x="Years",y="Spending",title = "Customer Spending on Companies per Year")
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your data is in a wide format given your original code. Best thing to do is to manipulate it to long format using `pivot_longer()` from `tidyr` so that you have three variables. Then it is easy to create a legend for your chosen variable. Do this with `aes()` in `geom_line()`. Remember that the variable that you want to show in different colours needs to be a factor. You can do this before the ggplot pipes or in it. I have manually adjusted the the title of the legend in `labs()`. There are various was to change the colours and you should be able to find some ways on the internet.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

Year <- 2009:2020
Apple <- cumsum(rnorm(12, 200, 22))
Intel <- cumsum(rnorm(12, 500, 12))
BOB <- cumsum(rnorm(12, 300, 8))
Airbus <- cumsum(rnorm(12, 500, 22))
Syntel <- cumsum(rnorm(12, 150, 15))
Google <- cumsum(rnorm(12, 500, 10))
Ebay <- cumsum(rnorm(12, 300, 1))

dataset <- data.frame(Year, Apple, Intel, BOB, Airbus, Syntel, Google, Ebay)
dataset <- dataset %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = Apple:Ebay, names_to = "Company", values_to = "values") 

ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Year, y = values)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = as.factor(Company))) +
  labs(x="Years",y="Spending", title = "Customer Spending on Companies per Year", colour = "Company")
```